# Javascript/Jquery: Script (that has nothing to do with form) is disabling the use of <select>, can anyone see why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that allows me to load pages/content into a div instead of reloading the page.  It also updates the back button, and allows to navigation through all the content.  I've used forms on this no problem and they work; however, haven't used a select inside these pages until now.

I added the select with options.  It loads, and then a second later, the select text disappears and acts as if nothing is in the select options.

I removed this script from the page, and everything works fine again.  I don't see whats in here that is interfering because this has nothing to do with the form itself.  I was hoping someone else would see what was causing this issue.

SCRIPT:

```
$(function(){

  $("a[rel='right']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();


    //get the link location that was clicked
    pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
    //to get the ajax content and display in div
    $.ajax({url:pageurl.replace('index.php', 'rightcolumn.php')+'&rel=right',success: function(data){  
      $('#WMS_NEW_right').fadeOut(500, function(){ $('#WMS_NEW_right').html(data).fadeIn(1000); }); 
    }
    });

    //to change the browser URL to the given link location
    if(pageurl!=window.location){
      window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);
    }
    //stop refreshing to the page given in
    return false;
  });

});

/* the below code is to override back button to get the ajax content without reload*/
$(window).on('popstate', function() {
    $.ajax({url:$(location).attr('href').replace('index.php', 'rightcolumn.php') +'&rel=right',success: function(data){
        $('#WMS_NEW_right').html(data);
    }});
});
```

HTML form that I am using...

```
<form class="formrelright" action="" method="POST">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
Option: <select name="option" /><option value="">Option</select><br />
Option2: <select name="option2" /><option value="">Option</option></select><br />
Option3: <select name="option3" /><option value="">Option</option></select><br />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing your select too soon.

```
<select name="option" />
```

should be

```
<select name="option"><option value="">Option</option></select>
```

Comment: oh wow.  I have no clue how I managed to do that.  I do know I did one and copied the others.  I updated the code and it works now.  I'm really intrigued by the fact that when I removed the script from the page, everything seemed to work.  Nonetheless, thank you for picking up on that!